# Underscore mixin error

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, underscore.js

I am trying to learn Grunt tasks from this below example
https://github.com/song-rate-mvc/angular-song-rate/tree/0.0.3

after command npm install, bower install during Grunt Dev i get the below error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _" in app.js file

the error occurs in file app.js at

```
angular.module("myApp", [
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]);
//error occurs in the below line.
_.mixin(_.string.exports());
```

Am i missing anything...

Comment: Have you imported Underscorejs library to your project? Usually that kind of error is shown when you don't have Underscorejs library imported.

Comment: In that case it's lodash apparently. Can you check if you have that directory: ```libs/lodash/```

Comment: yes, i have the directory libs/lodash